# How can I change default description of wpf components with AutomationProperties?

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, uiaccessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am developing an accessible WPF (C#) application in Visual Studio in Spanish. I am using JAWS screen reader. I have labeled in Spanish the MenuItems using `AutomationProperties.Name` in order for the screen reader to read them correctly.

```
<Button x:Name="PlayButton" Width="{Binding FontSize}" AutomationProperties.Name="Reproducir" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" >
    <Image Source="Icons/Play.png"/>
</Button>
```

My problem is the screen reader says a default description after the name I gave the component (e.g. button top activate press spacebar). This description is in English, but I want it to be in Spanish.
I have checked that the UI language and culture is Spanish-Spain and have changed the language in the component `Language="es-ES"`.

Comment: does this not work the same as on the web, setting the language at the top only changes the language of the page, it does not affect the language of the interface instructions as those are user preference settings. When you set language it lets the screen reader know how to parse text, it doesn't set system (screen reader) preferences.